# Failed to compile after i hit npm start

Tags: reactjs, terminal

This is my first time creating react page pretty i watch youtube tutorials, so I followed the steps but when I tried to deploy the react page to the browser or after i hit npm start the terminal said :

```
  Failed to compile.
    
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\#code\React Exercise\my-first-react\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in 'D:\#code\React Exercise\my-first-react'
    ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\#code\React Exercise\my-first-react\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in 'D:\#code\React Exercise\my-first-react'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

note that React page actually launch on my browser but my terminal has an error so it bothers me to start learning React it feels like there's something that I do wrong and I don't know what is.

So how can I successfully launch a react page without this kind of error? btw im using the latest node